# How to stop menu bar from dimming when focusing on a different monitor

Tags: macos, mojave, menu-bar, dual-screen

I have mojave (10.14.1) and use dark mode with each display having separate spaces (I have two screen in total). This means that there are two menu bars. Everytime I focus on a specific space, the menu bar of the other screen dims all the icons except for a few. How can I stop this dimming effect completely?

Comment: Wow, more than 4 years, and this is still an issue...